# PDO how to get auto_increment value from a table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, last-insert-id

I am creating a calendar in php and grabbing events from a database. We also have to insert events using prepared PDO statements. I can successfully create the new event and insert it into an event table. I also have to link and event with a family member.

```
$stmt = $handle->prepare("INSERT INTO events(name, description, starthour, meridian, eventdate)
  VALUES(:name, :description, :starthour, :meridian, :eventdate)");
$stmt->execute(array(
    "name" => $name,
    "description" => $description,
    "starthour" => "$starthour",
    "meridian" => "$meridian",
    "eventdate" => "$eventdate"
 ));

$stmt1 = $handle->prepare("INSERT INTO familymemberevents(familymemberID,eventID)
    VALUES(:familymemberID, :eventID)");
$stmt1->execute(array(
    "familymemberID" => $familymemberid,
    "eventID" => 
));
```

eventID auto-increments. Is there anyway I can get this number from the database?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: PDO has a last insert id function; http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php.

Comment: $lastId = $stmt1->lastInsertId(); , will return last event id. to know more -http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: i would like to suggest one thing use redbeanphp orm for handling data. using direct pdo is really paintful

Answer (score 3):

```
$stmt = $handle->prepare("INSERT INTO events(name, description, starthour, meridian, eventdate)
    VALUES(:name, :description, :starthour, :meridian, :eventdate)");
$stmt->execute(array(
    "name" => $name,
    "description" => $description,
    "starthour" => "$starthour",
    "meridian" => "$meridian",
    "eventdate" => "$eventdate"
));

$eventID = $handle->lastInsertId();

if($eventID){
    //Event Insert successful, continue with familymemberevent insert
    $stmt1 = $handle->prepare("INSERT INTO familymemberevents(familymemberID,eventID)
        VALUES(:familymemberID, :eventID)");
    $stmt1->execute(array(
        "familymemberID" => $familymemberid,
        "eventID" => $eventID
    ));
}else{
    //Event Insert failed - handle appropriately here
}
```

Comment: I think it is $handle->lastInsertId() instead of $stmt->lastInsertId()

Comment: @myoch Your are correct. Thanks for catching that. Fixed.